# JVM Crashing with JNI and RMI

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface, rmi

We use JNI to start an JVM. And in this JVM we use "LocateRegistry.createRegistry(JMXPORT);" to create registry. But the JVM always crash at Solaris with JDK1.6 ( It works fine with JDK1.5). The crash happens at the 256th line of UnicastRemoteObject(exportObject method)

I can work around the crashing by add -XX:+UseSerialGC to change the GC method. But i need to know the root cause.
It will be very appreciated for any help. Thanks.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0xfffffd7ff0f2b898, pid=28894, tid=4
#
# JRE version: 6.0_37-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.12-b01 mixed mode solaris-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x46b898]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0x94c8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000081b800):  VMThread [stack: 0xfffffd7ffe6af000,0xfffffd7ffe7af000] [id=4]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGFPE: si_errno=0, si_code=4 (FPE_FLTOVF), si_addr=0xfffffd7ff0f2b898

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000469f60, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000461a60, RDX=0x0000000000880000
RSP=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6a0, RBP=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6d0, RSI=0x0000000003300000, RDI=0x0000000000475500
R8 =0x000000000046c860, R9 =0xfffffd7ffee52490, R10=0x0000000000461b00, R11=0x00000000f9380000
R12=0x0000000000475500, R13=0xfffffd7ff1272fd0, R14=0x0000000000475d30, R15=0x00000000000cc010
RIP=0xfffffd7ff0f2b898, RFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6a0)
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6a0:   fffffd7ff199af30 000000000046c2e0
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6b0:   0000000000475500 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6c0:   fffffd7ffe7ae6f0 408f4000447a0000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6d0:   fffffd7ffe7ae710 fffffd7ff0f2b8e7
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6e0:   fffffd7ff199af30 000000000046c2e0
0xfffffd7ffe7ae6f0:   00000000004623c0 fffffd7ff0f37d99
0xfffffd7ffe7ae700:   00000000000cc010 fffffd7ff199af30
0xfffffd7ffe7ae710:   fffffd7ffe7ae720 fffffd7ff0f2b5da
0xfffffd7ffe7ae720:   fffffd7ffe7ae9c0 fffffd7ff1680c44
0xfffffd7ffe7ae730:   0000000000461970 000000000046c2e0
0xfffffd7ffe7ae740:   fffffd7ff1999388 fffffd7ff19a16e8
0xfffffd7ffe7ae750:   0000000000000000 000000000081cb70
0xfffffd7ffe7ae760:   0000000000000000 000000001ecf66a6
0xfffffd7ffe7ae770:   000000001f257d23 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae780:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae790:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7a0:   fffffd7ffe7ae878 00000000004a6530
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7b0:   0000000000000001 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7c0:   fffffd7ffe7ae7d0 fffffd7ff0e6fc92
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7d0:   0000000000517da0 00000000004a6520
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7e0:   00000000004a6530 00000000004a6908
0xfffffd7ffe7ae7f0:   000000000081b800 000000000047b280
0xfffffd7ffe7ae800:   000000000081bf10 000000000081bf20
0xfffffd7ffe7ae810:   000000000081c2f8 fffffd7ffe7aebb8
0xfffffd7ffe7ae820:   fffffd7ff1990100 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae830:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae840:   000000000045e450 fffffd7ff9c77300
0xfffffd7ffe7ae850:   fffffd7ffe010100 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7ffe7ae860:   fffffd7ffe7ae8a0 fffffd7ff0f7cf00
0xfffffd7ffe7ae870:   00000000004a6530 000000000045e450
0xfffffd7ffe7ae880:   0000000000000000 000000001ed00a99
0xfffffd7ffe7ae890:   0000000000000001 0000000000476c80 

Instructions: (pc=0xfffffd7ff0f2b898)
0xfffffd7ff0f2b878:   2c c0 4d 8b 4e 28 4d 89 01 4d 8b b4 24 08 01 00
0xfffffd7ff0f2b888:   00 49 8b fc 33 c0 41 ff d5 4c 8b 80 98 00 00 00
0xfffffd7ff0f2b898:   f2 41 0f 5a 40 28 f3 0f 59 45 f8 f3 4c 0f 2c c0
0xfffffd7ff0f2b8a8:   4d 8b 4e 28 4d 89 01 41 5e 41 5d 41 5c c9 c3 00 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000469f60 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000461a60 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000880000 is an unknown value
RSP=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6a0 is an unknown value
RBP=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6d0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000003300000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000475500 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000046c860 is an unknown value
R9 =0xfffffd7ffee52490 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000461b00 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000f9380000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000475500 is an unknown value
R13=0xfffffd7ff1272fd0: JVM_SupportsCX8+0x219000 in /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0xfffffd7ff0ac0000
R14=0x0000000000475d30 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000000cc010 is an unknown value


Stack: [0xfffffd7ffe6af000,0xfffffd7ffe7af000],  sp=0xfffffd7ffe7ae6a0,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x46b898]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0x94c8
V  [libjvm.so+0x46b8e7]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0x9517
V  [libjvm.so+0x46b5da]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0x920a
V  [libjvm.so+0xbc0c44]  sysThreadAvailableStackWithSlack+0x3a384
V  [libjvm.so+0xbb3986]  sysThreadAvailableStackWithSlack+0x2d0c6
V  [libjvm.so+0x531398]  JVM_IsSameClassPackage+0x2eb8
V  [libjvm.so+0x472384]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0xffb4
V  [libjvm.so+0x4725fa]  JVM_GetCPClassNameUTF+0x1022a
V  [libjvm.so+0x5ad0a0]  JVM_SupportsCX8+0x130d0
V  [libjvm.so+0x5ac55f]  JVM_SupportsCX8+0x1258f
V  [libjvm.so+0xb7f469]  JVM_RaiseSignal+0x1c8509
C  [libc.so.1+0x1149d4]  _thrp_setup+0xbc
C  [libc.so.1+0x114ca0]  _lwp_start+0x0

VM_Operation (0xfffffd7ffd58b7a0): ParallelGCSystemGC, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000000bba800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000000c4d800 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23, stack(0xfffffd7ffd0ff000,0xfffffd7ffd1ff000)]
  0x0000000000b7d000 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[10.182.73.206:34213]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22, stack(0xfffffd7ffd28a000,0xfffffd7ffd38a000)]
  0x0000000000ccd000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(1)-10.182.73.206" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=21, stack(0xfffffd7ffd38b000,0xfffffd7ffd48b000)]
  0x0000000000bba800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20, stack(0xfffffd7ffd48c000,0xfffffd7ffd58c000)]
  0x0000000000bb9000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=19, stack(0xfffffd7ffd58d000,0xfffffd7ffd68d000)]
  0x0000000000bb6800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18, stack(0xfffffd7ffd68e000,0xfffffd7ffd78e000)]
  0x0000000000bb5800 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=17, stack(0xfffffd7ffd78f000,0xfffffd7ffd88f000)]
  0x0000000000c0e000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-26999" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14, stack(0xfffffd7ffd96f000,0xfffffd7ffda6f000)]
  0x000000000086b800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12, stack(0xfffffd7ffdea7000,0xfffffd7ffdfa7000)]
  0x0000000000868800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11, stack(0xfffffd7ffdfa8000,0xfffffd7ffe0a8000)]
  0x0000000000865800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10, stack(0xfffffd7ffe0a9000,0xfffffd7ffe1a9000)]
  0x000000000085a000 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9, stack(0xfffffd7ffe1aa000,0xfffffd7ffe2aa000)]
  0x0000000000855000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8, stack(0xfffffd7ffe2ab000,0xfffffd7ffe3ab000)]
  0x0000000000849000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7, stack(0xfffffd7ffe3ac000,0xfffffd7ffe4ac000)]
  0x0000000000823800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6, stack(0xfffffd7ffe4ad000,0xfffffd7ffe5ad000)]
  0x0000000000821800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5, stack(0xfffffd7ffe5ae000,0xfffffd7ffe6ae000)]
  0x0000000000468800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1, stack(0xfffffd7fff600000,0xfffffd7fffe00000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x000000000081b800 VMThread [stack: 0xfffffd7ffe6af000,0xfffffd7ffe7af000] [id=4]
  0x0000000000881000 WatcherThread [stack: 0xfffffd7ffdd3e000,0xfffffd7ffde3e000] [id=13]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000000467200] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000000081b800
[0x00000000004677a0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000000bba800

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 60928K, used 816K [0x00000000f5800000, 0x00000000f9c00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 52224K, 0% used [0x00000000f5800000,0x00000000f5800000,0x00000000f8b00000)
  from space 8704K, 9% used [0x00000000f8b00000,0x00000000f8bcc010,0x00000000f9380000)
  to   space 8704K, 0% used [0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9380000,0x00000000f9c00000)
 PSOldGen        total 137216K, used 0K [0x00000000e0a00000, 0x00000000e9000000, 0x00000000f5800000)
  object space 137216K, 0% used [0x00000000e0a00000,0x00000000e0a00000,0x00000000e9000000)
 PSPermGen       total 22528K, used 9472K [0x00000000db800000, 0x00000000dce00000, 0x00000000e0a00000)
  object space 22528K, 42% used [0x00000000db800000,0x00000000dc1402f8,0x00000000dce00000)

Code Cache  [0xfffffd7ff9c00000, 0xfffffd7ffa000000, 0xfffffd7ffcc00000)
 total_blobs=280 nmethods=35 adapters=207 free_code_cache=49827264 largest_free_block=15680

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000  /****/bin/tlisten
0xfffffd7fe8fc0000  /****/lib/libgpnet.so.71
0xfffffd7fe8df0000  /****/lib/libtux.so.71
0xfffffd7feae10000  /****/lib/libbuft.so.71
0xfffffd7fe8db0000  /****/lib/libfml.so.71
0xfffffd7fe8d70000  /****/lib/libfml32.so.71
0xfffffd7fe9060000  /****/lib/libengine.so.71
0xfffffd7ffe8cd000  /lib/64/libpthread.so.1
0xfffffd7ffe8cb000  /lib/64/librt.so.1
0xfffffd7ffe880000  /lib/64/libsocket.so.1
0xfffffd7ffe7d0000  /lib/64/libnsl.so.1
0xfffffd7ffeeb0000  /lib/64/libm.so.2
0xfffffd7ffdcfc000  /lib/64/libthread.so.1
0xfffffd7fff110000  /lib/64/libc.so.1
0xfffffd7feadf0000  /****/lib/libutrace.so.71
0xfffffd7feadb0000  /****/lib/libgiconv.so.71
0xfffffd7ffd200000  /usr/lib/64/libCrun.so.1
0xfffffd7fe8000000  /****/lib/libtmjmx.so
0xfffffd7ffe8b0000  /lib/64/libmd.so.1
0xfffffd7ffe7b0000  /lib/64/libmp.so.2
0xfffffd7ff0ac0000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
0xfffffd7ffde3f000  /usr/lib/64/libsched.so.1
0xfffffd7ffdcfb000  /lib/64/libdl.so.1
0xfffffd7ffcdb0000  /lib/64/libm.so.1
0xfffffd7ffceaf000  /lib/64/libdoor.so.1
0xfffffd7ffcd70000  /usr/lib/64/libdemangle.so.1
0xfffffd7fe9000000  /****/lib/registry.so
0xfffffd7ff0a90000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
0xfffffd7ff0a40000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
0xfffffd7ff0950000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libjdwp.so
0xfffffd7ff0930000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libnpt.so
0xfffffd7ff0910000  /usr/lib/iconv/amd64/UTF-8%646.so
0xfffffd7ff08f0000  /usr/lib/iconv/amd64/646%UTF-8.so
0xfffffd7ff0a10000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
0xfffffd7ff08d0000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libdt_socket.so
0xfffffd7fe6bc0000  /****/lib/libtuxjni.so
0xfffffd7fe8ca0000  /****/lib/libtmib.so.71
0xfffffd7fe8c10000  /****/lib/libqm.so.71
0xfffffd7ff09f0000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pkcs11.so
0xfffffd7ffde60000  /usr/lib/amd64/libpkcs11.so
0xfffffd7ffdd10000  /lib/64/libcryptoutil.so.1
0xfffffd7ffdbf0000  /usr/lib/security/64/pkcs11_softtoken.so
0xfffffd7ffdbb0000  /usr/lib/64/libsoftcrypto.so.1
0xfffffd7ffdb80000  /lib/64/libgen.so.1
0xfffffd7ff09c0000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
0xfffffd7fef430000  /****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/librmi.so

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.compiler=NONE -Dmyapp.jmx.auth=tux -Djava.security.policy= -Dmyapp.jmx.accessfile=/****/jmx/jmxaccess.properties -Dmyapp.jmx.addr=rmi://****:26999 -Xms200m -Xmx500m -Dmyapp.tlisten.nlsaddr=//****:27789 -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre
PATH=/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/amd64/:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/bin:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin/amd64:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin:/****/bin:/****/bin/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/ksh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xccfbb0], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xccfbb0], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x43f880], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x43f880], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x43f880], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x43f880], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGUSR1: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0xb81a00], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0xb81a00], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIG39: [libjvm.so+0xb84870], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000008
SIG40: [libjvm.so+0x43f880], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:                      Oracle Solaris 11 Express snv_151a X86
     Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                           Assembled 04 November 2010

uname:SunOS 5.11 snv_151a i86pc  (T2 libthread)
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE infinity, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:1.16 1.15 0.84

CPU:total 2 (32 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8191612k(1152580k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.12-b01) for solaris-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_37-b06), built on Sep 24 2012 11:42:33 by "" with Workshop 5.8

time: Fri Oct 26 09:29:22 2012
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

And following is the core dump stack trace

```
Reading librmi.so
t@4 (l@4) terminated by signal ABRT (Abort)
0xfffffd7fff22dd1a: _lwp_kill+0x000a:   jae      _lwp_kill+0x18 [ 0xfffffd7fff22dd28, .+0xe ]
(dbx) where
current thread: t@4
=>[1] _lwp_kill(0x4, 0x6, 0xffffff02cd0cbc00, 0xfffffd7fff22e54b, 0x0, 0xfffffd7ffe7addc0), at 0xfffffd7fff22dd1a 
  [2] thr_kill(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff2224dd 
  [3] raise(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff1ce9f1 
  [4] abort(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff1a41a1 
  [5] os::abort(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff16403e4 
  [6] VMError::report_and_die(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff178f66a 
  [7] JVM_handle_solaris_signal(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0eff703 
  [8] signalHandler(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0eff88e 
  [9] __sighndlr(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff224d66 
  [10] call_user_handler(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff217a1c 
  [11] sigacthandler(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff217c43 
  ---- called from signal handler with signal 8 (SIGFPE) ------
  [12] GCAdaptivePolicyCounters::update_counters_from_policy(0x475500, 0x3300000, 0x880000, 0x461a60, 0x46c860, 0xfffffd7ffee52490), at 0xfffffd7ff0f2b898 
  [13] PSGCAdaptivePolicyCounters::update_counters_from_policy(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0f2b8e7 
  [14] PSGCAdaptivePolicyCounters::update_counters(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0f2b5da 
  [15] PSScavenge::invoke_no_policy(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff1680c44 
  [16] PSMarkSweep::invoke(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff1673986 
  [17] VM_ParallelGCSystemGC::doit(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0ff1398 
  [18] VM_Operation::evaluate(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0f32384 
  [19] VMThread::evaluate_operation(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff0f325fa 
  [20] VMThread::loop(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff106d0a0 
  [21] VMThread::run(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff106c55f 
  [22] java_start(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7ff163f469 
  [23] _thrp_setup(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff2249d4 
  [24] _lwp_start(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0), at 0xfffffd7fff224ca0
```